# SLF4J logger does not print anything to console

Tags: java, slf4j

I want to add logging into my Java application using AspectJ and Slf4j. Basically the aspect just delegeates to the slf4j methods in this fashion:

```
package my.domain.com;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public aspect MyAspectLogger {

    private Logger logger;

    public MyAspectLogger() {
        this.logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger( "MyAspectLogger" );
    }

    pointcut callSomeFunction(): call(* de.my.domain.MyClass.*());

    before() : callSomeFunction() {
        logger.error( "**** (Before) Called something in MyClass ****" );
    }

    after() : callSomeFunction()  {
        System.out.println( "**** (After) Called something in MyClass ****" );
    }
}
```

**Why does the `System.out.println()` print the message but the `logger.error()` does not print the message?**

Comment: Do you have a SLF4J implementation like logback on your classpath?

Comment: Thanks to your hint: After adding `slf4j-simple` to my classpath, the logger is functional.

Comment: Then I suggest that either @nille85 writes an answer and kiltek accepts it so as to close the question or kiltek deletes the question altogether. And BTW, I have edited the subject and tags so as to relate to the real problem. This is in no way related to AspectJ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make sure that there is a SLF4J implementation like logback on the classpath.

Comment: And also that implementation is not NOOP.